# go compilation: remove personal info from executable

Tags: go, compilation, exe, executable

I need to compile a go program for release and I have noticed that in the executable there are written all sort of personal information such as the original folder where the program is on my pc.

Is there a flag to avoid distributing all this "personal" bytes?
Is it possible to rename all the function names during compilation?

thanks

Comment: A production binary should be built in a clean environment anyway, which should have no identifiable user paths. No, the compiler does not offer any option to obfuscate the compiled binary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `-trimpath` argument to `go build`.

From `go help build`:

> -trimpath
>
> remove all file system paths from the resulting
>   executable.       Instead of absolute file system paths, the recorded file
>   names         will begin with either "go" (for the standard library),         or a
>   module path@version (when using modules),         or a plain import path
>   (when using GOPATH).

Comment: but with this I don't see any difference. plus: is there a way to mask functions names?

Answer (score -1):

To answer your second question:

> Is it possible to rename all the function names during compilation?

No, of course not.

(And you also cannot change the syscall numbers to obfuscate what your program does.)

((If you are trying to do fhishy stuff: Don't.))

Comment: Infact I don't wanto to change the syscall numbers (like wtf...), is that if I have written a function called "verification" I would prefer it be called "jcdn5geinj"....... Maybe I'm just afraid that having spent more than 200h developing something some childish hacker would reverse engineer my code in 1h to resell it

Comment: @dhim You should rethink your business model. Even if you name your function "kdfeijefkn" it will still be easy to decompile (and spot that it does important stuff).

Comment: sure but still less clear